# Problems with library(lambda), currying and SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

So I run into some troubles while (ab?)using
lambda.pl.

I do a "use_module(library(lambda))."
in the first lines of a file that
I consult via ["a.prolog"].
Then I get an "undefined procedure ()/3"
and some gibberish afterwards.

The same happens for any order of use_modules.
It happens whether I load a.prolog via
[...], consult or as a script from the cmdline.
I reduced the script to the currying-example from Rosseta code 
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Currying#Prolog

```
use_module(library(lambda)).

:- initialization(main, main).

main :-
    N = 5, F = \X^Y^(Y is X+N), maplist(F, [1,2,3], L),
    print(L).
```

It doesn't work.

It works, however, if I a manually load 'lambda'
at the swipl-prompt and immeditately consult
a.prolog. Then the goal N=5,.... works just fine.

If I, however, first consult a.prolog; then manually
use_module and then run the query, I get the error.
Reconsulting doesn't help onwards.

Somehow, the first command at the prompt needs to
be use_module.

Or do I get the loading mechanism completely wrong?
If so, please apologize; but I would love get a
hint how to solve this.

Comment: Minor comment: rather use `F_2` in place of `F`.  In this manner you are making clear that `F_2` is an incomplete goal that needs two further arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common error when first using modules.

Please have a look at this line:

```
use_module(library(lambda)).
```

This is just a **fact**, saying "`use_module(library(lambbda))` holds".

What you want instead is a **directive**.

A *directive* is a term with primary functor `(:-)/1`. That is, you want:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

**EDIT**: For the particular case of `library(lambda)`, I would like to add that there is a page with a lot of useful information about it that is a bit hard to find:

**http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord**

"[Hiord](http://www.fjords.com/fjords/)" stands  for **higher order**.

Comment: Oh ... this is embarassing. Thanks so much. Indeed that was my mistake.

Comment: If it's any consolation: This is a quite common issue, I have seen this also from several students, sometimes because even their instructor's slides have this mistake!

Comment: You basically spared me from showing such slides ;-)

Comment: Nice! I think it is great that you introduce students to `library(lambda)`. Please note the [homepage](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord): It also contains an example for arithmetic that is - in my opinion - even better because it is more general, using declarative integer arithmetic! I hope you find it useful.

Comment: There really should be a permission error as SICStus Prolog does.